# how to call web form in vb.net using (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

I am a beginner to ASP.NET. Can you tell me how to call a new page from the existing page?

In VB.NET, by executing the statement "Form2.show()", a new page will be loaded. In the same way, how do I load a new page in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

```
Server.Transfer ( "NewPage.aspx" );
```

[Server.Transfer Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Response.Redirect("yourpage.aspx")
```

From MSDN: [Response.Redirect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309.aspx)